# Airy's equation on $\mathbb R_-$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, hyperbolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

I am interested in Airy's equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x)=-\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}(t,x)$$
on a bounded or semi-bounded domain, e.g. on $(-\infty,0)$. In order to obtain a group of isometries as propagator in $L^2(-\infty,0)$, two boundary conditions have to imposed - e.g., $u'(0)=0$ and either $u(0)=0$ or $u''(0)=0$. But then it seems that the spectrum of the operator is far too large, so I doubt that this operator does not generate a semigroup in $L^2(-\infty,0)$ at all, regardless of the imposed boundary conditions. Is it so? Has anybody ever proved well-posedness of the above equation in some reasonable function or distribution space?

Comment: On a bounded interval, $A=iD^3$ has self-adjoint realizations and then $e^{itA}$ is a unitary group. On a half line, $D^3$ has unequal deficiency indices $(2,1)$, so this approach won't work.

Comment: On a bounded interval, the deficiency index is $3$, so you need this many boundary conditions (not two).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Indeed! There are several works suggesting that two b.c. have to be imposed on the right and one on the left endpoints; but in these works I can never find a "clean" well-posedness theorem in a "nice" function space (ideally, a Sobolev or Lebesgue space, but I'd be happy even with one space from Triebel's zoo; ideally, by means of a unitary $C_0$-group). Remarkably, the equation on $\mathbb R$ is governed by a propagator that is just the convolution of an integral kernel based on Airy's function and the Fourier transform of the initial data, so a group might exist after all.

Comment: Yes, on $\mathbb R$ the $L^2$ theory is straightforward: $A=iD^3$ is essentially self-adjoint on $C_0^{\infty}$, so again $e^{itA}$ is a unitary group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operators $A=-\,\partial_x^3$ with domain $\mathscr D(A) =
\left(H^3\cap H_0^2\right)(\mathbb R_-)$ and $A^\ast=\partial_x^3$
with domain $\mathscr D(A^\ast) = \left(H^3\cap H_0^1\right)(\mathbb
R_-)$ are $m$-dissipative on $L^2(\mathbb R_-)$. This follows from
$\Re\langle Au,u\rangle =0$ for $u\in\mathscr D(A)$ and $\Re\langle
A^\ast v,v\rangle =-\,\frac12\,|v'(0)|^2\leq 0$ for $v\in\mathscr
D(A^\ast)$. Therefore, $A$ and $A^\ast$ generate $C_0$-contraction
semigroups on $L^2(\mathbb R_-)$, by the Lumer-Phillips
theorem. Moreover, the semigroup $\{e^{tA}\}_{t\geq0}$ consists of
isometries (though not of unitary operators for $t>0$, as $iA$ is not
selfadjoint, see Christian's comment above).

One can also directly solve the initial-boundary value problem
$$
\left\{ \enspace
\begin{aligned}
  & u_t + u_{xxx} = f(t,x), & (t,x)\in \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R_-, \\
  & u\bigr|_{x=0} = h_0(t), \enspace u_x\bigr|_{x=0} = h_1(t), \\
  & u\bigr|_{t=0} = u_0(x)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
(and similar for the operator $\partial_t-\partial_x^3$ with
one in place of two boundary conditions), e.g., by using the Laplace
transform with respect to $x$. See [N. Hayashi, E. Kaikina, Nonlinear
Theory of Pseudodifferential Equations on a Half-line, North-Holland,
2004,](https://www.elsevier.com/books/nonlinear-theory-of-pseudodifferential-equations-on-a-half-line/hayashi/978-0-444-51569-8) which contains a chapter on linear problems.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting question and I do not know the answer. I would start at something like

*N. A. Larkin*, [**Correct initial boundary value problems for dispersive equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2008.03.055), *J. Math. Anal. Appl.* **344** (2008), no. 2, 1079--1092.